# Coffeescript two-dimensional array comprehension

Tags: json, coffeescript, d3.js

I'm getting lost in nested JSON and Coffeescript. I have JSON data that looks like this:

```
{
"top-level": {
  "first_array": [y1,y2,y3...],
  "second_array: [y1,y2,y3...]... etc
}
```

Each array needs to be converted to a two-dimensional array with x and y values where x is just the index. So

```
"first_array": [[x: 0, y: y1],[x: 0, y: y2]...]
```

And then I need to return just an array of arrays

```
[[first_array], [second_array]]
```

I also need this to work without knowing explicitly the names of "first_array", etc.

I've tried to generalize this since I think it is just a basic javascript data manipulation question, but if it is helpful, I'm trying to format the data for the D3.js function d3.layout.stack used here: http://bl.ocks.org/1134768

Thanks!!

Comment: Wouldn't the resulting array look like this:
`"first_array": [[x: 0, y: y1],[x: 1, y: y2]...]`

Comment: Arrays can't have string indices, so it'd be: `"first_array": [{x: 0, y: y1}, {x: 0, y: y2}...]`

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is what you want to accomplish:

```
obj = {"top-level": {"first_array": ["y1","y2","y3"], "second_array": ["y1","y2","y3"]}}
({x: xi, y: yi} for yi,xi in ar for name,ar of obj['top-level'] )
```

Yields

```
   [ [ { x: 0, y: 'y1' },
    { x: 1, y: 'y2' },
    { x: 2, y: 'y3' } ],
  [ { x: 0, y: 'y1' },
    { x: 1, y: 'y2' },
    { x: 2, y: 'y3' } ] ]
```